# Explanation of states, worlds and models?

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

Can someone explain to me how the concepts of states, models and worlds work together in Kripke semantics?

I've been trying to piece together how the parts work are linked together but cannot figure it out.

From what I understand, a model M consists of worlds. Now as far as I can gather from that, states would be the some as worlds. However, I cannot find this confirmed anywhere.

Could someone explain to me how these concepts work? Obviously, I've googled them, but most texts are quite complicated to grasp with little experience on the subject. Even textbooks remain quite vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, worlds and states are the same thing. Some people prefer one term over the other, but in either case the difference is merely terminological. If you want to learn more about how modal logic works, you could start by reading the [SEP entry on Modal Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/). There are also plenty of good texts out there. I like Chellas's [Modal Logic: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521295157), Popkorn's [First Steps in Modal Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521057930), and van Benthem's [Modal Logic for Open Minds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157586598X).